# My json string is being returned in an incorrect format, can I use $.ajax to get the data anyway?

Tags: jquery, web-services, json

EDIT: It seems that the formatting of the json string is not the problem. Instead I'm not seeing the json string in the Firebug response section and yet ajax error handlers aren't being thrown.

Hi!

So I've got a web service setup so that it will return a very simple json string:

```
{"A":1,"Total":1}
```

After reading several threads on stackoverflow and even on the jquery documentation page for $.ajax, I learned that the correct formatting for the json string is to have each value within double quotes as well.

```
{"A":"1","Total":"1"}
```

I'm assuming that is why my jquery ajax is not working:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://test/testServices/InfoService.svc/GetInfoStats?pId=76&mId=2117",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(xml,txtStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(xml + " " + txtStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (msg, test) {
        alert("JSON DATA LOADED! " + msg);
        $(".MainContainerBottom").html(msg);
    }
});

$('.log').ajaxError(function () {
        $(this).text('Triggered ajaxError handler.');
    });
```

Firebug's Console window is telling me that the GET was "200 OK 398ms" consistently and if I check test variable it returns success as well. msn returns null though!
The Params and the Headers section of Firebug also looks good but the Response section is empty.

I was also messing around with the dataType of the $.ajax and had it as jsonp at first and firebug returned an error stating

```
Invalid Label
{"A":1,"Total":1}
```

So I know the information is coming back correctly but I can't access it. I'm assuming it's because of the formatting issue I began this post with. Is that correct?

Assuming I don't have the ability to modify the web service myself, what can I do to get the json data out and into my script?

Thank you very much! <3
John

EDIT: For Guffa

```
Response Headers
Content-Length  39
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Fri, 12 Nov 2010 21:58:57 GMT

Request Headers
    Host    test
    User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.9) Gecko/20100824 Firefox/3.6.9
    Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*
    Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
    Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Keep-Alive  115
    Connection  keep-alive
```

Final Edit:
I spoke to the guy who setup the web service for us and apparently there was some special restrictions on the information being sent back. He setup some permissions for our application to access the data and it worked flawlessly.

Thanks to everyone for your help! I'm really surprised by the amount of people who responded and tried to help me out. I'll definitely be sticking around the stackoverflow community now and hopefully one day I can help out others as well :)

Comment: what's the url look like? and is it on the same domain?

Comment: If the response is empty then you're not actually getting anything back. Otherwise, you would see the JSON data serialized as a string in the response.

Comment: are we supposed to use eval or JSON.parse as others suggested.

Comment: If Firebug shows you that the response body is empty, you can be pretty sure that it is empty.

Comment: When I paste the URL into my browser, I get a download prompt. If I open it up in a text browser I get : {"A":1,"Total":1}

Comment: That's odd. What browser/version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong with the original JSON string. Values doesn't have to be strings, they can be numbers.

You have to look for the error elsewhere. Add an error handler in the Ajax call, so that you can get any information about what might be going wrong.

When you fetch data as JSONP, it expects the result wrapped in a callback call: `callback({"A":1,"Total":1});`. The code is executed when it's returned, and as there isn't a callback call around the object, the brackets around the object literal is instead interpreted as a code block, and the property names are interpreted as code labels. Code labels have to be identifiers, not strings, hence the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the callback and jsonp. Good to know :)

Comment: I updated my original post with, what I think, is the error handler!

Comment: @Robodude: Actually you have two error handlers, but that should not be a problem. At least one of them would be triggered, but there should be some information sent to the `ajaxError` handler that you could use it it's triggered. Do you get an error message?

Comment: Thanks again Guffa. Unfortunately, none of the error handlers are giving me any information. They aren't even triggered. Very strange :(

Comment: @Robodude: I tried your code, and it works just fine, which suggests that what you get from the server is not what you think. Try to find out exactly what it returns, and if it's content type is `application/json`.

Comment: I'm going to update the original post with more information in just a moment.

Comment: I know the web service is working properly because when I paste the URL into the web browser I get the download prompt asking me to save "application/json" type file from my web service. When I open it up with notepad, I see the json string.

Comment: I also confirmed using Fiddler that the data is coming back in "TextView" but it is still not showing up in the response according to FireBug. What's up with that? ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse('{"A":2}')['A']
```

Strings have to be wrapped in double quotes, numeric literals don't. It's something else. Can you provide the *real data* and the real url, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `contentType` declaration from your $.ajax call. `contentType` defines the content-type of the data you're sending to the server, not what you're expecting back. This can confuse a simple GET request.

Comment: Tried it but it didn't help. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of .net are you using? if is >3.5 the format of your message is different. Try the following:

```
      success: function (msg, test) {
        var newMes = msg.d; 
     alert(newMes.A);
```

Comment: I get this: 

msg is null
[Break on this error] var newMes = msg.d;

Comment: oh I'm using 4.0 if it matters :)